# Replacement of Hibernate @Cache with JPA for @OneToMany relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching

At the moment I'm updating some `@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` annotations with the JPA equivalent `@javax.persistence.Cacheable`. This works well on `@Entity` level, but cannot be done for `@OneToMany` relationships.

My question is similar to [Can we use JPA2 annotations to cache associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365297/can-we-use-jpa2-annotations-to-cache-associations) but I think it's appropriate to ask again after 10 years while it was self-answered with "*there is no replacement for the hibernate annotation*" such a long time ago.

**Now my question**: Are there replacements in the `javax.persistence` or `jakarta.persistence` packages for `@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache`?

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Cacheable
public class Tutor
{
   @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache  <---- REPLACE this with JPA
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="tutor")
   private Set<Student> students;
}

@Entity
@javax.persistence.Cacheable
public class Student
{
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="TUTOR_FK")
   private Tutor tutor;
}
```

BTW: If someone is reading this question in the context of performance improvements, I recommend these articles

- [How to use JPA2's @Cacheable instead of Hibernate's @Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663979/how-to-use-jpa2s-cacheable-instead-of-hibernates-cache)
- https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache
- https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
- https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/